# Quasar + AmCharts Redering time delay

Tags: delay, loading, amcharts4, quasar-framework

I am developing a webapp using quasar and there I used AmCharts with Axios for the API.
When data is received from the API, 5~6 charts are then rendered on the page.

The problem is there is a significant delay until the charts to be displayed after the component mounted.
I'd like to show a loading spinner during this time.

How should I detect all components are finished rendering?
Or is there some other way around for me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) is called when the DOM is fully updated (that means, components are rendered again).
You could try this in your charts component, a [watcher](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that checks when the API is fetched, provided you already have a loader component that shows only if a show variable is set to true:

```
watch:{
   values(newVal){
      this.nextTick().then(()=>{
         this.show= true;
      });
     }
}
```